# Error when trying to access rails c production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I'am trying to access rails console in my production environment, but I get this error. Actually I'm working with amazon ec2 ubuntu instance by ssh connection.

I've tried to reinstall gems but nothing happens

This is my output:

```
home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:30:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name Untitled folder (NameError)
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:30:in `block in qualified_const_defined?'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:29:in `each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:29:in `inject'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb:29:in `qualified_const_defined?'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:376:in `qualified_const_defined?'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `block in watch_namespaces'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:143:in `map'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:143:in `watch_namespaces'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:643:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /home/ubuntu/Rails/nanda_mx/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It starts from this line `config/environment.rb:5` is something interesting on that line?

Comment: The weird thing seems to be "Untitled folder". Do you have something like this anywhere in your project? In the config files perhaps?

Comment: It looks like it's trying (and failing) to load something out of a directory called `Untitled folder`. Is that where you created your rails app?